# Timer doesn't work

Tags: c#, timer

Is the first time that I use timer, so probably I'm doing something wrong.

My code is something like this:

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button2.PerformClick();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // random code here
            timer1.Interval = 5000;
           timer1.Start();
           timer1_Tick(null,null);

    }
```

What I want to do with this is: execute the random code, then wait the timer interval and execute the Tick (that will do a 'click' in the button again, for execute again the same), and repeat this for ever.

Sorry if is a easy mistake, I'm starting with this and don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks you for read me! :D

Comment: Well.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/writing-a-good-title

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? This code seems to have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Timer event (for every kind of timers) doesn't need to be manually called by you.

You set its event handler method, set the interval and start it.
The underlying framework calls your `Tick` event when it is time to call it.

So you need to put your *random code* in a sub that you could call from the `Tick` event and from your button click event. Also, you should think to block further activations of the timer. You could disable the button and, when you have finished with your *random code* and the conditions are true, stop the timer and reenable the button.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    stopTheTimer = false;
    YourCommonMethod();
    button2.Enabled = false;
    timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick
    timer1.Interval = 5000;
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    YourCommonMethod();
}
private void YourCommonMethod()
{
    // execute your 'random' code here
    if(stopTheTimer)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        timer1.Tick -= timer1_Tick;  // disconnect the event handler 
        button2.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please look also the answer from @Idle_Mind because he has made a good point. I have adjusted my answer to reflect its observation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's you go. . . .

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // random code here
        timer1.Interval = 5000;
        timer1.Start();
        timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;

    }

    void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Your timing code here.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Wire up the Tick() event only **once**, preferably thru the IDE so you don't end up with multiple handlers and your code running more than once for each Tick() event.

*In the example below I've wired it up in the constructor as an alternative...but don't do this **and** wire it up thru the IDE or it will fire twice for each Tick().

You probably just want to call Start() in the Button handler and then call your "random code" in the Tick() event like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        timer1.Interval = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds;
        timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick; // just wire it up once!
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!timer1.Enabled)
        {
            Foo(); // <-- Optional if you want Foo() to run immediately without waiting for the first Tick() event
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Foo();
    }

    private void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Random Code @ " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

}
```

This isn't that much different than the other answers, but wiring up the Tick() event multiple times is a serious flaw...

Comment: You are absolutely right. The Tick event should be disconnected or just associated one time at the Form_Load event or in the designer. I have changed my answer to reflect your observation. (and upvoted yours)